# Can I use old Crush or RC bottles for bottling?

Tags: bottling

My wife found some cheap soda bottles at an antique store and I was wondering if anyone knew if I can use them for bottling my beer.

Comment: I imagine that if you sterilize them properly and can get tops that fit, it should be possible to use them. I can't think of a reason why it would *not* be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may be able to be recapped, but you may want to reconsider if they are not brown/amber bottles.  The other colors of glass can lead to troubled brews (e.g. [here](http://byo.com/stories/wizard/article/section/121-mr-wizard/701-glass-colors-blow-off-method-mr-wizard))

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully used coke bottles on a stout. They worked great and it was definitely a surprise to some people when the cracked it open and it wasn't coke that they were drinking.

I'd just check to make sure that they aren't cracked or anything, and make sure your caps will fit them.

If they are clear, be sure to store them in a dark place until ready to consume, as well!